# Mainline kernel supported Raspberry Pi competitor? (no GPU needed)

Tags: linux, kernel, raspberry-pi

The Raspberry Pi uses [its own kernel fork](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux).

For a headless server (no GPU needed), is there a device with similar specs, performance-wise, that can use the vanilla mainline kernel from [kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org)?

Answer (score 1):

Both Beaglebone Black and Wandboard (at least Quad) have support in vanilla 3.12 and 3.13 to a point where they can boot and be reached via ethernet. Full support for all peripherals is a work in progress though. Robert Nelson maintains sets of patches trailing mainline, with better peripheral support.

Answer (score 0):

> The Raspberry Pi uses its own kernel fork.

Yep, because of the ARMv6 processor.  I don't know why that port hasn't been included in the mainline kernel, actually -- I think there is some Broadcom proprietary blobs in it, although I'd think this could be separated out from the ARM implementation.

But maybe not.  The architectures under `[src]/arch/arm` in the vanilla source all look very specific.  However, most distros now have an ARMv7+ version (compiled from the same mainline kernel source) supporting all kinds of devices -- e.g., here's a list from "[archlinux.arm](http://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv7)".  [Fedora](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Architectures/ARM) and [Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM) have them too.

Pandaboard and Beagleboard appear to be the more established things in the ARMv7+ category, but the list seems to be growing all the time -- it includes [these chips](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allwinner_A1X), which are used on various such dev boards.

Comment: Didn't know that the allwinner a1x was available on those cubieboards (a favorite chipset of mine that I thought was only available on cheaper android tablets). I think I'm gonna add one to my holiday wishlist this year

Comment: raspberrypi/linux/ doesn't use the newish DeviceTree code layout. Until they rework it to do so, no merge

Comment: Ooh, I found a comment that says [kernel 3.13 _might_ mainline the BeagleBone Black](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/beagleboard/QRpdLOFSxwM/HXfTdNWg6lcJ) - didn't know they were that close!